# what are pre-aggregated tables in vertica

Tags: database, database-design, vertica

what are pre-aggregated tables in vertica ? How to implement the pre-aggregated table in vertica ?
i found this term mentioned for performance optimization in vertica database, but couldn't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you link to the document page in question? I can't find mention of it. In conjunction with your other question ([how to implement aggregated tables in vertica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699647/how-to-implement-aggregated-tables-in-vertica)), you are likely going to have to implement your own aggregation, either outside of Vertica or with SQL queries.

There is the possibility that you might benefit from a table view, but that shouldn't have any different performance than a query on the original unaggregated table.