# how to implement aggregated tables in vertica

Tags: database, vertica

how to implement aggregated table in vertica database? does vertica provide any inbuilt options.
If it is not possible, what is the alternative ? I basically want to avoid the overhead of updating in both fact table and aggregated table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an aggregated table, I have rolled my own in the past. Using some sort of script running via cron and keeping track of what was previously aggregated.

I would also highly recommend setting up projection(s) specifically tuned for the types aggregate query you desire. If done properly, you can see some pretty good results.